# AsyncTaskLoader: deliverResult, when the variable(for cache) in AsyncTaskLoader will be null(means called)

Tags: caching, asynctaskloader

variable for caching will be initially null and once the AsyncTaskLoader loader execution completed its value will be in that variable.

If we want to do the execution again after completion of the first one, how can we clear the cached variable value, so that it will be set to null again and forceLoad() can be executed?